# How do I find the array created when I press the "Print Screen" key on windows 10?

Tags: arrays, keyboard-shortcuts, printscreen

Probably when I press the print screen key on the keyboard the image on the screen creates a array and then converts it to an image. Is there any way to find this? Or a way to convert the resulting screenshot to an array ?

Comment: What do you mean by "array". Yes in the end of the day, the screenshot taken is just a bunch of bytes somewhere in the memory and you may be able to access it with probably any app, that is able to access the clipboard. But still, you would need to correctly interpret the bytes, because for sure, there is some metainformation stored with it ...

Comment: Each pixel in the image has an RGB code and these codes are listed as arrays. I want to find these arrays. As an example, the array you see below is an image in 2x2 format. In the first row, 2 pixels from left to right are green, and in the second row, 2 pixels from left to right are black.
[[[  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]]

 [[  0   0   0]
  [  0   0   0]]]